# What are these two drains for?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom

I have an unfinished basement and do not have any experience with plumbing a bathroom. I assume the two pipes protruding from the floor are toilet (on the left) and either sink or shower (on the right).

[image]

Where am I supposed to connect the toilet, shower and sink?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the large pipe is 12 1/2", 13 1/2" or so (it could be up to 14 1/2")from the wall that will surely be for your toilet. The pipe on the right will be for your tub. The plastic that it protrudes through allows the bit of maneuvering room to get it to line up with the tub drain or it could be used for a shower, although it will be offset instead of the center. This pipe should be somewhere about 16 or so inches away from the wall on the right that is NOT in the picture. You will still need a drain for the sink.

There should be a 2" line like the ones inside the stud wall in your picture, just not there.
I would presume there is another pipe on the other side of the room?

Comment: +1  :unless the third line is there out of the pic, the 2" line with the black cover could be used for a vanity sink. the black cover is probably covering a larger hole in the concrete to facilitate an offset.

Comment: I think that the third line is actually the leftmost line in the stud wall (16" to the left of the toilet). If you look closely on the picture there's a "T" coming out of that line.

Comment: If the room is wide enough to allow all the plumbing on one side of the bathroom, then that's cool. Make sure you have 30" allowed for the toilet space to anything, tub, sink cabinet. It may be a safe assumption that the proposed sink drain could be made with the tee you point out, but confirm that it does go to the main line (the 4' line) when you open it all up. Pouring water down the tee with the toilet flange in place, or the pipe cut off at least will allow you to confirm.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll verify that it is indeed connected to the main line.